# Problemas ao ler todas as linhas de um Excel com OLEDB e C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, iis, oledb

Estou desenvolvendo um programa para importar planilhas `Excel` com linguagem `C#`, usando o componente `OLEDB`, ao importar uma planilha com 100547 linhas o programa só consegue ler 54046.

Segue o código-fonte:

```
public class ReadExcel
{
    public string ConnectionExcel(ExcelUpload excelUpload)
    {
        //connection String for xls file format.
        if (excelUpload.fileExtension == ".xls")
        {
            excelUpload.excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + excelUpload.fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
        }
        //connection String for xlsx file format.
        else if (excelUpload.fileExtension == ".xlsx")
        {
            excelUpload.excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelUpload.fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
        }
        else
        {
            excelUpload.excelConnectionString = "";
        }
        return excelUpload.excelConnectionString;
    }

    public DataTable readArqExcel(string excelConnectionString, DataSet ds)
    {
        //Create Connection to Excel work book and add oledb namespace
        OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
        excelConnection.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        if (dt == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        //Numero de planilhas contidas no excel
        String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
        int count = 0;

        //excel data saves in temp file here.
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            excelSheets[count] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            count++;
        }

        OleDbConnection excelConnection1 = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
        string query = string.Format("Select * from [{0}]", excelSheets[0]);
        using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, excelConnection1))
        {
            dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        }

        excelConnection.Close();

        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

Eu testei o `IIS 8` (REMOTE SERVER) e o `IIS Express` (servidor local do Visual Studio), notei que no servidor `IIS Express` o código funciona perfeitamente, mas , no `IIS 8` o código acaba lendo o arquivo ao meio.

É algum tipo de configuração de servidor Web?

Comment: da uma olhada pq excel tem limite de linhas por página

Comment: Bom dia Eduardo, então no excel esta normal, tem todas as informaçoes certinho.
Eu to achando que seria no IIS mais nao encontrei ainda nenhuma configuração de memoria ou algo do tipo.
Pq no IIS express funciona ele importa as 100547 linhas, agr no IIS dentro do servidor ele corta pela metade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consegui resolver o problema através da string de conexao com o Excel conforme abaixo, alterando o parametro IMEX =2 PARA

```
if (excelUpload.fileExtension == ".xls")
        {
            excelUpload.excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + excelUpload.fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";
        }
        //connection String for xlsx file format.
        else if (excelUpload.fileExtension == ".xlsx")
        {
            excelUpload.excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelUpload.fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";
        }
```